# Associating ViewPager with navigation tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

Is there any way to associate each fragment in the ViewPager with a certain navigation tab? So when we flip right/left ,the right tab will be highlighted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TabLayout from the Material Design support library.

See the "Tabs" paragraph in the [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) that introduces the library:

> However, if you are using a ViewPager for horizontal paging between
>   tabs, you can create tabs directly from your PagerAdapter’s
>   getPageTitle() and then connect the two together using
>   setupWithViewPager(). This ensures that tab selection events update
>   the ViewPager and page changes update the selected tab.